Sharepoint with intermittent behavior and send a message error when I try to delete a column
I have a site in which I have added a couple of columns (in SharePoint Designer) to be able to update the data in a form, the problem is that after I add these columns, the views no longer allow me to open them, update them, delete them or generate a new one and, when I try to delete these new columns (List Settings->"Name field"->Button Delete), the site experiences intermittence to the extent that it is not possible to access normally and starts sending the error message of "Something went wrong. This is a temporary issue, so try again in a few minutes" and I have to wait approximately an hour to be able to log in again (from SharePoint Designer, I can't log in either, since it sends me the same error).
In the views part, when I try to update, delete or create, it sends the message "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has occurred." and again the site starts intermittently and I have to wait another hour for the site to be able to enter (This after having added the columns).
Any ideas? This is driving me crazy since it is not possible for me to do anything. I tried deleting old items in the list, since the threshold had been exceeded (5000 items max.) and I have emptied the Recylce Byn, but not even with This has changed the situation.
I appreciate the help in advance. Greetings.



